# how to use module values in another modules in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to use the first module output value in another module

current scenario -

```
modules
--network
  --main.tf
  --output.tf
  --variable.tf
--server
  --main.tf
  --output.tf
  --variable.tf
node.tf
```

I created VPC in the network modules

```
resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = var.vpc_name
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "default" {
  name          = "my-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/16"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.default.id
}
```

and also output in the same directory /modules/network = cat output.tf

```
output "subnet_id" {
  value = google_compute_subnetwork.id
}
```

and now I have another module called a server and there I want to use subnetwork that is my subnet  id

cat /modules/server/main.tf

```
resource "google_compute_address" "internal_ip" {
  name         = "my-internal-address"
  project      = "fivenodeautomation"
  subnetwork   =  *******              #google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "10.0.1.0"
  region       = "us-central1"
  purpose      = "GCE_ENDPOINT"
}
resource "google_compute_address" "static" {
  name       = "vm-public-address"
  project    = "fivenodeautomation"
  region     = "us-central1"
}
```

how do I access this subnetwork value in server modules
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `module.network.subnet_id`?

Comment: @MarkoE  i tried it says "No module call named "network" is declared in module.mysubnet."

Comment: You need to call both modules in the `node.tf` file. Then, you will be able to reference the module output. AFAIK, I do not think it is possible to reference the output defined in one module in another module as it requires the resource to be previously created. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html